# Reading data by port manipulation (Arduino Due)

Tags: arduino-due, port-mapping

I have shorted the 23rd pin of port A with 3.3v output pin (i.e. tieing 23rd pin of port A to logic high). Now I am trying to read the 23rd pin of port A by using following code-

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // put your setup code here, to run once:
  char print_str[40];
  REG_PIOA_PER = 0x00800000;   //Write 1's to A register pins to override other peripherals and allow GPIO use for pins
  REG_PIOA_ODR = 0x00800000;   //Set A register pins to INPUT
  sprintf(print_str, "\n%08X", REG_PIOA_PDSR);
  Serial.println(print_str);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

According to the code, the serial output should be 0x00800000. But I am always getting 0. Could you please tell me, what is going wrong?

Comment: 23rd pin is PA22 ... did you connect the correct pin?

Comment: Check the value of `REG_PIOA_WPMR`.

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the GPIO library for SAM. There is an initialization missing. https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-GPIO/blob/master/src/Hardware/SAM/GPIO.h